# How to customize datatables row?

Tags: jquery, datatables

How can I customize the row of my jquery datatables?
I wanted to put a color to the row if it meets the condition isEvent == 1.
I followed this code from datatables community [thread/example](http://live.datatables.net/cezewiqe/381/edit) but the `==` is not working.

```
  searchResultsTable = $('#searchResultsTable').DataTable({
        bFilter: false,
        bLengthChange: false,
        searching: false,
        orderable: true,
        autoWidth: true,
       
        columns: [
            { data: null, render: 'department', title: 'Department', orderable: false, className: 'dt-center' },
            { data: null, render: 'employeeName', title: 'Employee Name', orderable: false, className: 'dt-center' },
            { data: null, render: 'recordDate', title: 'Date', orderable: false },
            { data: null, render: 'timeIn', title: 'Time In', orderable: false, className: 'dt-center' },
            { data: null, render: 'timeOut', title: 'Time Out', orderable: false, className: 'dt-center' },
            { data: null, render: 'day', title: 'Day', orderable: false, className: 'dt-center' },
            { data: null, render: 'eventTime', title: 'OT-UT-Errand', width: '50px',orderable: false, className: 'dt-center' },
            { data: null, render: 'eventName', title: 'Event', orderable: false, className: 'dt-center' },
            { data: null, render: 'total', title: 'No. of Hours Worked', orderable: false, className: 'dt-center' },
             { data: null, render: 'isEvent', title: 'isEvent?', orderable: false,visible:true, className: 'dt-center' }
           

        ],
        createdRow: function (row, data, index) {
            if (data[9]==1) {

                /*   $(row).addClass('blue');   //add class to row*/
                $('td', row).eq(2).css('font-weight', 'bold');
                $(row).css('background-color', 'yellow');   //add class to row
            }
            //add style to cell in third column
        }
    });
```

I already tried `data[9] > 0` ,`data[9] != 0` ,`data[9] === 1` but when I use the `data[9] = 1`
it applies to all the rows, and I had it `consol.log(data[9])` it returns all 1. But on my rendered table and actual data object i have multiple `0` and `1` also tried set the column's `visible:true` option still not working.

Comment: Are you sure `data[9]` is an integer value? It would help to see an example of the data contained in the table

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes from server-side it's an integer however I get `undefined` when I `console.log(typeof(data[9]))`

Comment: What do you see if you do `console.log(data)`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I see my data objects

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan , it seems it work when I directly access data properties instead of using `data[9]` I just access directly using `data._myproperty`

Answer (score 0):

Just accessed `data` directly. Like `data._isEvent`